# Simple jQuery - hide text box

Tags: jquery

I am new jQuery, playing around with it. I would like text box when I click button but it doesn't work in that way.

```
<input type=text id=txt></input>
<input type=button id=btn value="Click Me"></input>

$document.ready(function() {
    $("input#btn").click(function() {
        $("input#txt").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: A usefull thing is the error console. If you use Firefox press CTRL+SHIFT+J. This helps a lot, I wouldn't have seen your mistake either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){      
    $("input#btn").click(function(){
      $("input#txt").hide();
    });
});
```

missed the `()` around `document` you can use the short cut also like

```
$(function(){

//your code here

});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as `$document.ready(`

Try doing `$(document).ready(`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to put "" around your html elements. After that you can fix it like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click Me" onclick="$('#txt').hide()"/>
```